# web.Folders / GetFolder "value does not fall within the expected range" exception

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

> //The following line works fine

SPList list = web.Lists["docLibName"];

> //The following line raise exception "value does not fall within the expected
>   range"

SPFolder = web.Folders["docLibName"];

Comment: I can retrieve my document library as SPList but when I try to get it as SPFolder I get the exception

Answer (score 0):

The key in a SPListCollection is the **title** of the list. The key in an SPFolderCollection is the **name** of the folder. This is a subtle but important difference.

The title of the list can be changed in the list settings. The name of the list is determined upon creating the list, and cannot be changed through the normal SharePoint user interface (although it can be changed through Windows Explorer and SharePoint Designer).

The name can be derived from the list or library's url or path. The title is not necessarily reflected in the path.

For example, if you create a library with the name "MyGreatLibrary" and then later change the title to "My Okay Library", its root folder will still have a name of "MyGreatLibrary":

```
// Use the library's TITLE
SPList myList = web.Lists["My Okay Library"]; 

// Use the library's site-relative path, or NAME
SPFolder myFolder = web.Lists["MyGreatLibrary"];
```

Comment: Thanks,yes the static/internal name, you can get it also from visual studio by opening a connection to the sharepoint and get it from the properties of the list, anyway I'm already using the Static name and it's working with me in other webparts for getting the list and the folder,I think it's something else